# Error : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, list

I have a query that contains hexadecimal codes and when there is a hexadecimal code I want to apply a background-color to the previous data in my table, but it's written

> background-color:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.St‌​ring]

to each line in my source code.

Here is my code :

```
<tr>
            @{
                int nbItems = ViewBag.listDonnees.Count;
                var hashCodes = new List<String>() { "#FFFFFF", "#FFD700", "#FF6347" };

                for (int cpt = 0; cpt < nbItems; cpt++)
                {
                    string colorcode = string.Empty;
                    if (cpt + 1 < nbItems)
                    {
                        var mylist = (IEnumerable < dynamic >) ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt];
                        colorcode = mylist.FirstOrDefault(s => hashCodes.Contains(s));
                    }
                    if (colorcode != string.Empty)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:@ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt+1]">colorcode</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var str = String.Join(",", ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt]);
                        <td>str</td>
                    }
                    cpt++;
                }
            }
        </tr>
```

And I would like replace "colorcode" by the current data and listDonnees is a List < List < string > >

My model :

```
dac = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dac.SelectCommand = cmd1;

            dsp = new DataSet();
            dac.Fill(dsp, "donnees");

            List<List<string>> listDonnees = new List<List<string>>();

            foreach (DataRow row in dsp.Tables["donnees"].Rows)
            {
                List<string> l = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    l.Add(row[i].ToString());
                }

                listDonnees.Add(l);
            }
            list.Add("donnees", listDonnees);
```

My Controller :

```
        public ActionResult AfficheRspic002(string Tdate_d, string Ddl_fampic, string Ddl_donnee, string Ddl_detail, string Ddl_caracteristique, string Ddl_poste, string Ddl_ilot, string Ddl_nposte, string Ddl_atelier, string Ddl_tposte)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> list = model.getPICv2(Tdate_d,Ddl_fampic, Ddl_donnee, Ddl_detail, Ddl_caracteristique, Ddl_poste, Ddl_ilot, Ddl_nposte, Ddl_atelier, Ddl_tposte);

        ViewBag.listEntete = list["entete"];
        ViewBag.listJO = list["jo"];
        ViewBag.listPrevision = list["prevision"];
        ViewBag.listCommandeEt = list["commande"];
        ViewBag.listDonnees = list["donnees"];

        return PartialView();
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Why not put all this logic in the controller in the first place?

Comment: Can you show your `ViewBag.listDonnees` in controller ?

Comment: Because I think it's a matter of posting. I edit my post

Comment: *Your problem is that: listDonnees[cpt] is a List*, yes, a duplicate absolutely.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer same user

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's why the code was so familiar ^^

Comment: Yes it's your code but I still have a mistake ^^

Comment: How to solve my problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned

> listDonnees is a List < List < string > >

then of course, `@ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt+1]` will be list of string. You should store colorcode in `ViewBag`, not list of colorcode.

May be if you post how you are selecting color from list then we can give you more concrete answer.